# How to cancel navigation away from subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

How do I prevent navigating away from a particular subform when a user clicks on a different navigation tab? One of the subforms is pretty complicated, and I want to allow the user a chance to stop the navigation to be able to save all their hard work before they leave the subform.

I have an Access database with a 2-level navigation form. Basically, it looks like this:
[image: Access database with navigation]

Assuming the user is currently viewing the "Important stuff" form in the Navigation form's subform (as is pictured above), and that they still have an unsaved record or anything that would warrant them not losing, I'd like to warn/prompt them with a message box and allow them to cancel the navigation.

I've already tried using the `Unload` event of the `ImportantStuff` form, e.g.

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim closeConfirmation As Integer

    closeConfirmation = MsgBox("There is unsaved data. Are you sure you want to leave?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo)
    If closeConfirmation = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

But, although I'm prompted as I'd expect, cancelling (via clicking "No") doesn't stop the navigation, and the Unimportant stuff gets shown to me. If I open the ImportantStuff form directly, i.e. outside of the Navigation form, clicking "No" on the prompt *does* prevent the ImportantStuff form from closing.

I also tried using the NavigationButton's `Exit` event, but it correlates with the user's focus exiting the button, like when they interact with the ImportantStuff form, and not when they navigate away from that button.

How can I prevent navigating away from a particular subform?

Comment: Shouldn't record automatically save when navigating to another tab?

Comment: I believe you're correct. The example project discussed here is simplified - my actual implementation has a complicated subform that allows entry of multiple items into a temp table, so I'm still looking to be able to allow the user to review/save their work if they're not done.

Comment: Don't really understand issue. Hasn't user done due diligence to review their work before clicking on another tab? Why a temp table? I've never used temp table for user data entry.

Comment: Your point is most definitely valid, and I appreciate that a better design wouldn't need an "are you sure" dialog. But, regardless of my reasoning or debatable design choices, my question still stands. Is there a way to cancel navigation between tabs?

Comment: Nature of Navigation Form is only one form is loaded at a time. Don't see any way to cancel but maybe could 'return' to the other tab, essentially reload first form.

Comment: would you be able to use the [important form]  close event instead?  Cancel eventual close if user not done?